# YouTrack workflow - HTTP request

Tags: youtrack

is it possible to perform a HTTP request in YouTrack workflow?

I would like to create a workflow that calls some REST API whenever user logs some time on an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YouTrack workflow rules run inside a pretty restricted sandbox. Currently, there're no means to do what you want.

Comment: This is discussed in this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-10671 , consider adding this link to your answer

Answer (score -1):

YouTrack Workflows are providing some methods to communicate with foreign servers:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/2017.1/Workflow-REST-API.html

A simple example (taken from the link above):

```
// post new issue content to third-party tool and add response as a comment

when issue.becomesReported() {
    addHttpHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    var response = doHttpPost("http://server.com/issueRegistry", issue.description);
    issue.addComment(response)
}
```

I've never worked with timetracking inside YouTrack, so no concrete example is here. But on page linked above, there is a section with "Custom Time Tracking with the Harvest Web Service", maybe you can adapt some code from there.